# How do I securely shred a file/data from ios/android in an app's sandbox?

Tags: encryption, android, ios

I'm working on a cryptographically secure app and I need to delete keys that are stored in a keybag in the sandbox. I want to be able to shred individual keys beyond recovery.

How do I do this using C++?

Comment: This looks like a mobile programming question. Migrating.

Comment: In iOS, at least, the "keychain" is saved outside the app's sandboxed file system. I don't have an a ready answer for you on how to securely "shred" entries in the keychain. The way flash memory filesystems work might make this difficult, since they rotate the physical storage location of data each time it's written in order to deal with the fact that flash memory has a limited number of write cycles before it fails.